# "Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)" when i executed cypress with CRACO

Tags: webpack, cypress, create-react-app, sass-loader, craco

I have a project with CRA 5 and I needed to add some aliases so I had to install craco but I have a problem, when I run my tests with cypress I get this error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
./src/components/Common/Inputs/Checkbox/scss/checkbox.scss 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> @import '../../../../../scss/main.scss';
```

I have tried many ways, also overriding the sass loader:

```
const path = require('path');

const sassRegex = /\.(scss)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

module.exports = {
  webpack: {
    extensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'js', 'jsx'],
    alias: {
      '@layout': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Layout'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components'),
      '@contexts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/contexts'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/hooks'),
      '@lib': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/lib'),
      '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/pages'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/scss'),
      '@common': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Common'),
      '@icons': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Common/Icons'),
      '@inputs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/Common/Inputs'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets'),
    },

    configure: (webpackConfig, { env, paths }) => {
      const overrideSassLoaderConfiguration = {
        test: sassRegex,
        exclude: sassModuleRegex,
        include: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'sass')],
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
      };

      webpackConfig.module.rules = [...webpackConfig.module.rules, overrideSassLoaderConfiguration];

      return webpackConfig;
    },
  },
};
```

but nothing seems to work, what am I doing wrong?...